# How to fetch database(oracle) table one by one means first it show first row then on the submit it will show the next row and so on

Tags: mysql, oracle, jsp

Below is my code but it select only 1st row again and again ...
        <%

```
    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
       Connection c=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","system","system");

    String ss=(String)session.getAttribute("ssss");
    String sss=(String)session.getAttribute("sss");
    PreparedStatement P=c.prepareStatement("Select * from QUESTION where EXAMNAME=?");
    P.setString(1,sss);

    ResultSet rs=P.executeQuery();
  if(rs.next())
   { %>
   <form action="newjsp11.jsp" method="post">
       Welcome <%=ss%><br>
       <input type="text" name="abcd" value="<%= rs.getString(1)%>"><br>
       <input type="radio" name="abc" value="<%= rs.getString(2)%>"><%= rs.getString(2)%>
       <input type="radio" name="abc" value="<%= rs.getString(3)%>"><%= rs.getString(3)%>
       <input type="radio" name="abc" value="<%= rs.getString(4)%>"><%= rs.getString(4)%>
       <input type="radio" name="abc" value="<%= rs.getString(5)%>"><%= rs.getString(5)%><br>
       <input type="submit" name="Submit"><br><br>
   </form>

      <% }
    %>
```

Here String ss is Student name and sss is examname ...

Answer (score 0):

I dont't have java on my computer right now, but this link might be helpful for you. I'm guessing your problem is that you don't iterate over result of statement.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/processingsqlstatements.html

So your code should look more-less (if your code works ofc) like this:

```
    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
       Connection c=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","system","system");

    String ss=(String)session.getAttribute("ssss");
    String sss=(String)session.getAttribute("sss");
    PreparedStatement P=c.prepareStatement("Select * from QUESTION where EXAMNAME=?");
    P.setString(1,sss);
    ResultSet rs=P.executeQuery();
while (rs.next()) {

    %>
   <form action="newjsp11.jsp" method="post">
       Welcome <%=ss%><br>
       <input type="text" name="abcd" value="<%= rs.getString(1)%>"><br>
       <input type="radio" name="abc" value="<%= rs.getString(2)%>"><%= rs.getString(2)%>
       <input type="radio" name="abc" value="<%= rs.getString(3)%>"><%= rs.getString(3)%>
       <input type="radio" name="abc" value="<%= rs.getString(4)%>"><%= rs.getString(4)%>
       <input type="radio" name="abc" value="<%= rs.getString(5)%>"><%= rs.getString(5)%><br>
       <input type="submit" name="Submit"><br><br>
   </form>

      <% }
    %>
```

Comment: Using while instead of if gives the whole record at once which i don,t want